# JavaScript regex expression - replace all matches?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering why a specific website uses the following regex statement in document.referrer

`document.referrer.replace(/\*/g,'%2a')`

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to understand, what `/\*/g` means. I found, that `/g` is a global variable, but what does `/\*` mean and why would someone trying to extract a path from the referrer? I wasn't able to figure it on my own. Thanks in advance for your answer. I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: In javascript regular expressions start and end with `/`, so `/\*/` is a regular expression that matches the `*` character. The escape `\*` is there because `*` by itself has a special meaning within regular expressions, so in this case that meaning is bypassed by escaping the asterisk so it just means the character "*"

Comment: FYI see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions, especially the section on "Escaping".

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. May I ask, why u didn't answered it instead of commenting?

Comment: @robscure Are you refering to me or Peter B ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement replaces each astersik `*` of the referrer with the string `%2a` using a regular expression. The string `%2a` represents the URL encoded representation of the asterisk (`*`). This means, you can use the value in an URL without side-effects. If you e.g. have a URL and want to have a question mark (`?`) in it, you need to escape the question mark, otherwise it indicates that the GET parameters start from there.

However, it is better to use the built-in function `encodeURIComponent()` instead to escape the URI characters.

---

Your regular expression means the following:

- `/` in the beginning and in the end mark the start and end of the expression (do not have a meaning beyond this).
- `\*` selects an asterisk. because `*` has a special meaning in Regex, it is escaped with a slash.
- `/g` is the global selector, which means it should replace each and every asterisk in the string (not just the first one)

Answer (score 0):

Regex `/\*/g` can be break down to this:

```
/ - Regex delimiters - start and end
\* - Escape sequence for literal `*`. In regex `*` means from 0 to any occurrences. 
g - modifier flag. (Global)
```

So `document.referrer.replace(/\*/g,'%2a')` replaces `*` to `%2a` - some strange way to encode url components.

It would replace `My Re/f *is Good*` to be `My Re/f %2ais Good%2a`

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. I appreciate your answer!